# Trying to write unit test cannot work it out?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Write a unit test for `addInventory()`. Call `redSweater.addInventory()` with parameter `sweaterShipment`. Print the shown error if the subsequent quantity is incorrect. Sample output for failed unit test given initial quantity is 10 and `sweaterShipment` is 50:

> Beginning tests. UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory() Tests complete.Note:
>   UNIT TEST FAILED is preceded by 3 spaces.

```
  // ===== Code from file InventoryTag.java =====
  public class InventoryTag {
    private int quantityRemaining;

    public InventoryTag() {
      quantityRemaining = 0;
    }

    public int getQuantityRemaining() {
       return quantityRemaining;
    }

    public void addInventory(int numItems) {
      if (numItems > 10) {
         quantityRemaining = quantityRemaining + numItems;
      }
    }
  }// ===== end =====



   // ===== Code from file CallInventoryTag.java =====
    public class CallInventoryTag {
       public static void main (String [] args) {
           InventoryTag redSweater = new InventoryTag();
           int sweaterShipment;
           int sweaterInventoryBefore;

           sweaterInventoryBefore = redSweater.getQuantityRemaining();
           sweaterShipment = 25;

           System.out.println("Beginning tests.");

           // FIXME add unit test for addInventory
           System.out.println("Tests complete.");
       }

     }// ===== end =====
```

Comment: sorry but where do you set your initial quantity? what is is preceded by 3 spaces, what that means?

Comment: read after it says System.out.println("Beginning tests."); that is where I need to write the code for this to work.

Comment: You set it after System.out.println("Beginning tests.");

Comment: you have asked how to write tests and added tag unit-testing I was showing you how to write unit tests :) . Print the shown error? which error? and why there should be an error?

Comment: what you wrote below was too advanced CallInventoryTagTest.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
   @Test(expected=YourException.class)

Comment: you need to edit the part where it says // FIXME add unit test for addInventory it should be like public double getNum() or something. I am really confused and I am worrying for this test. please respond asap

Comment: What you're posting here is not a proper Java unit test.  You _can_ exercise Java code by running a main method and running things, but @vmrvictor 's answer below shows the proper way to do it.   The reason why your Test annotation is failing is because you need to import the proper library/classes, and any decent IDE will do that for you.

Comment: eclipse will help you to import the classes to compile, if you write after //FIXME that is not a unit test and we are not here to do your homework, but we can help you and I am trying to do so

Comment: How would a run a main method. How do I do that>

Comment: @Oceanman Do not vandalize your questions in that manner. That's unacceptable behavior here! Note that you can simply delete your question unless there's an upvoted or accepted answer given.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution the class is looking for (it took me a while to figure out the particular solution they wanted):

```
// ===== Code from file InventoryTag.java =====
public class InventoryTag {
   private int quantityRemaining;

   public InventoryTag() {
      quantityRemaining = 0;
   }

   public int getQuantityRemaining() {
      return quantityRemaining;
   }

   public void addInventory(int numItems) {
      if (numItems > 10) {
         quantityRemaining = quantityRemaining + numItems;
      }
   }
}
// ===== end =====

// ===== Code from file CallInventoryTag.java =====
public class CallInventoryTag {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      InventoryTag redSweater = new InventoryTag();
      int sweaterShipment;
      int sweaterInventoryBefore;

      sweaterInventoryBefore = redSweater.getQuantityRemaining();
      sweaterShipment = 25;

      System.out.println("Beginning tests.");

      // FIXME add unit test for addInventory
      /* Your solution starts here  */    
       redSweater.addInventory(sweaterShipment);

      if (sweaterInventoryBefore + sweaterShipment != redSweater.getQuantityRemaining()) {
         System.out.println("   UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()");
      }

      /* End of your solution*/    

      System.out.println("Tests complete.");
   }
}
// ===== end =====
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be located in `src/main` for source code and `src/test` for tests.
Then when you add a test for a class `A` in `package a;` and located at `src/main` then you write `ATest` in `package a;` located in `src/test`.

in your example the test class should look similar to:

```
public class CallInventoryTagTest {
   @Test(expected=YourException.class)
   public static void shouldThrowYourExceptionWhenX () {
       //given
       InventoryTag redSweater = new InventoryTag();
       int sweaterShipmen=25;
       int sweaterInventoryBefore;
       //when
       // that's what you need to write after your FIXME
       sweaterInventoryBefore = redSweater.getQuantityRemaining(); 
       redSweater.addInventory(sweaterShipmen)  //calling addinventor with parameter sweaterShipment
       //then
       fail("should throw an error because of X");
   }

 }
```

Comment: I need to write code after System.out.println("Beginning tests."); and I cannot think of anything to fix it. I really need this it is urgent please respond.

Comment: @Oceanman you have written that in your test you have to call addInventory with parameter sweaterShipment --> here that is done, but I do not understand why you need an error

Comment: an error for me is an exception, if you just throw an exception then your test will fail you have to either catch it or either use this annotation that says you expect this error.

Comment: Beginning tests.
   UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()
Tests complete.

Comment: If you want to have this output you just write --> System.out.println("Beginning tests. UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory() Tests complete.") //but why you do need this output, why is failing?

Comment: Call redSweater.addInventory() with parameter sweaterShipment. Print the shown error if the subsequent quantity is incorrect. Sample output for failed unit test given initial quantity is 10 and sweaterShipment is 50:

Comment: I need to call a method to check inventory

Comment: I do not see any check inventory method in your code, either in your question

Comment: what is that you have posted? That doesnt look like runable code? im confused

Comment: Not using @test that would be wrong. I want to use if statements to find the right one and print it yet I cannot. I am confsued bout that

Comment: I got the code and fixed it but this part just needs to be fixed

Comment: Define stubs for the methods called by the below main(). Each stub should print "FIXME: Finish methodName()" followed by a newline, and should return -1. Example output: 
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish computeAverage()
Avg: -1

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodStubs{

   /* Your solution goes here  */

   public static void main(String [] args) {
      int userNum1;
      int userNum2;
      int avgResult;
      MethodStubs stubTester = new MethodStubs();

      userNum1 = stubTester.getUserNum();
      userNum2 = stubTester.getUserNum();
      avgResult = stubTester.computeAverage(userNum1, userNum2);

      System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

It feels like homework.

I think your teacher expects a simple math test to show that InventoryTag is not inited
successfully when a number less than or equal to 10 is provided.

Something like:

```
// ===== Code from file CallInventoryTag.java =====
public class CallInventoryTag {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
       InventoryTag redSweater = new InventoryTag();
       int sweaterShipment;
       int sweaterInventoryBefore;

       sweaterInventoryBefore = redSweater.getQuantityRemaining();
       sweaterInventoryBefore = 10;
       sweaterShipment = 50;

       System.out.println("Beginning tests.");

       // FIXME add unit test for addInventory
       redSweater.addInventory(sweaterInventoryBefore);
       redSweater.addInventory(sweaterShipment);

       if (sweaterInventoryBefore + sweaterShipment != redSweater.getQuantityRemaining()) {
           System.out.println(" UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()");
       }

       System.out.println("Tests complete.");
   }

 }// ===== end =====
```

The test fails because the condition in method addInventory prevents to add 10 or less items to the inventory.

Comment: "It feels like homework." so what? this has nothing to do in an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// ===== Code from file InventoryTag.java =====
public class InventoryTag {
   private int quantityRemaining;

   public InventoryTag() {
      quantityRemaining = 0;
   }

   public int getQuantityRemaining() {
      return quantityRemaining;
   }

   public void addInventory(int numItems) {
      if (numItems > 10) {
         quantityRemaining = quantityRemaining + numItems;
      }
   }
}
// ===== end =====

// ===== Code from file CallInventoryTag.java =====
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CallInventoryTag {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      InventoryTag redSweater = new InventoryTag();
      int sweaterShipment;
      int sweaterInventoryBefore;

      sweaterInventoryBefore = redSweater.getQuantityRemaining();
      sweaterShipment = scnr.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Beginning tests.");

      // FIXME add unit test for addInventory
      redSweater.addInventory(sweaterShipment);
      redSweater.getQuantityRemaining();
      if (sweaterShipment <= 10) {
         System.out.println("   UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()");
      }
      /* Your solution goes here  */

      System.out.println("Tests complete.");
   }
}
// ===== end =====
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).